# Use Schema.org's 'WebSite' and 'Article' combined or individually

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

Whats is good, combine `WebSite` and `Article` or use individually?

For example:

Schema of `example.com` (home):

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "WebSite",
  "name": "",
  "url": "",
  "potentialAction": {
    "@type": "SearchAction",
    "target": "{search_term_string}",
    "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
  }
}
</script>
```

Schema of a one post `example.com/example-post/` (article):

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Article",
  "headline": "",
  "image": {
    "@type": "ImageObject",
    "url": "",
    "width": ,
    "height": 
  }
</script>
```

Now my question is, in the articles (`example.com/example-post/`), I must place the schema separately (as above) or in combination with the `WebSite` like this:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org/",
      "@type": "WebSite",
      "name": "",
      "url": "",
      "potentialAction": {
        "@type": "SearchAction",
        "target": "{search_term_string}",
        "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
      }
    },
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "Article",
      "headline": "",
      "image": {
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "url": "",
        "width": ,
        "height": 
      }
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "must"? Do you have a specific goal (e.g., a consumer to support)?

Comment: I think your combined example is invalid. You can't list entities like that. Place them in separate scripts or use @graph. I'd go for separate scripts as it is more broadly supported.